# Hide or show field comparing two other fields in Sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have two people picker column called Current User and Issue Owner. I want third field hide/show based on comparison between two people picker column. If people picker column have same value I need to show it else hide it.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script src="/sites/risk/Style%20Library/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script><script src="/sites/risk/Style%20Library/sputility.min.js"></script><script>

//$(document).ready(function(){

 var currentuser = SPUtility.GetSPField('Current User');
 var issueowner = SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue Owner');

 var HideOrShowOthersField=function(){
 var currentuserValue = currentuser.GetValue();
 var issueownerValue = issueowner.GetValue();

 if(currentuserValue!=issueownerValue)
 {

 SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue Owner Review Status').Hide();

 }
 else
 {


 SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue Owner Review Status').Show();

 }
 };
 HideOrShowOthersField();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message ?

Comment: No error message but it doesn’t work. The hide show didn’t work. I verified JavaScript library location.

Comment: I tried adding alert and no matter what the input field is, else statement is getting executed

Comment: Found the issue. The issue was not the code but the column. The type of column input were not same somehow. I changed both to string and it worked.